# Android passing data on drag

Tags: android, listview, android-viewholder

What is the full-proof way of passing data with drag and drop?

In my situation I have two lists and i can drag element from one to another.
So the list from which we drag already has data associated with it.
From what I have searched the usual way is storing data by views setTag() and getTag() methods. This is also what I would do, but since both lists use view-holder pattern, the actual data would be stored in holder. And the holder would then be set as views tag.
However I have also heard that you should never store data in views or in holder (im using view-holder pattern in list adapters).

So what would be the best way to pass data from one list to another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to store data in root activity or fragment:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
        {
            private ListView list1;
            private ListView list2;
            private int dragPosition;


    ...
        protected class myDragEventListener implements View.OnDragListener {

        // This is the method that the system calls when it dispatches a drag event to the
        // listener.
        public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

            // Defines a variable to store the action type for the incoming event
            final int action = event.getAction();

            // Handles each of the expected events
            switch(action) 
            {

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                    // save the position in one list
                    dragPosition = somePosition;
                        return true;

                case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                    //do what you want with other list
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }
```

maybe, [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html#DesignDragOperation) will be helpful.